# Oracle CASE statements

Tags: oracle, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a conditional statement in Oracle. There's a table for customers' accounts.

The logic is: If the Account_Close_Date contains values, it means the account has been closed by the customer, so the 'Status' should be "closed". Otherwise, the 'Status' should be "Open".

I write something like this:

```
select 
CASE Account_Close_Date WHEN null THEN 'Open'
ELSE 'Closed' END as Status, 
Account_Close_Date 
from customer_account_Table
```

However, it doesn't work. The "Status" is all "closed", even if there is no value in "Account_Close_Date".

[image]

Comment: `is null` -->>> `WHEN IS null THEN`

Comment: It throws the error "missing expression"

Comment: The other poster meant `WHEN [date-column] IS null THEN ...` - he expected you to be able to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE` "statements" do exist, but only in PL/SQL, not in plain SQL. What you have in your `SELECT` statement is an example of a `CASE` **expression**.

`CASE` expressions have two syntactical forms: *searched* and *simple*. You have an example of a *simple* `CASE` expression, one where the conditions are equality conditions. Problem is, in the three-valued logic of SQL, nothing is ever **equal** to `NULL`. Your condition is "if so-and-so-date equals `NULL`, then..." which is never `TRUE`.

Instead, use the *searched* syntax (already shown in a comment under your question):

```
CASE WHEN so-and-so-date IS NULL THEN ... ELSE ... END as ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use brackets:

```
SELECT Account_Close_Date, (CASE WHEN Account_Close_Date IS NULL THEN 'Open' ELSE 'Closed' END) as status FROM customer_account_Table;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/186d47/9

Comment: Parentheses ("brackets" are something different) are not necessary.